# In Reporting Services, the Table Details is not displaying in the preview

Tags: reporting-services

I put a table into my report with labels in the first column and mappings in the second column, but when I click on the preview (in the IDE) the table does not show up.

The "Initial Visibility" is set to "Visible".

I'm using VS 2005 Team Explorer Edition (Which is open from Sql Server 2005 BI)

Here is an sample XML (code), if that might help.

```
         <TableRow>
          <TableCells>
            <TableCell>
              <ReportItems>
                <Textbox Name="labelRID">
                  <Style>
                    <FontFamily>Times New Roman</FontFamily>
                    <FontSize>12pt</FontSize>
                    <TextAlign>Right</TextAlign>
                    <PaddingLeft>2pt</PaddingLeft>
                    <PaddingRight>2pt</PaddingRight>
                    <PaddingTop>2pt</PaddingTop>
                    <PaddingBottom>2pt</PaddingBottom>
                  </Style>
                  <ZIndex>7</ZIndex>
                  <CanGrow>true</CanGrow>
                  <Value>RID:</Value>
                </Textbox>
              </ReportItems>
            </TableCell>
            <TableCell>
              <ReportItems>
                <Textbox Name="textboxRID">
                  <Style>
                    <FontFamily>Times New Roman</FontFamily>
                    <FontSize>12pt</FontSize>
                    <TextAlign>Left</TextAlign>
                    <PaddingLeft>2pt</PaddingLeft>
                    <PaddingRight>2pt</PaddingRight>
                    <PaddingTop>2pt</PaddingTop>
                    <PaddingBottom>2pt</PaddingBottom>
                  </Style>
                  <ZIndex>6</ZIndex>
                  <CanGrow>true</CanGrow>
                  <Value>=Fields!rid.Value</Value>
                </Textbox>
              </ReportItems>
            </TableCell>
          </TableCells>
          <Height>0.25in</Height>
        </TableRow>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Microsoft's forum here was my problem.

"Select Table and press 'F4' there you can see Data Tab in that you have a property called No Row there you can print a text when there is no data returned from the dataset. Example 'No Data Available'."

So basically since I have no data coming through at this point (client hasn't provided any yet), my table with the labels will not show up.